# When creating an angular project using angular cli inside the google drive using ng command

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, warnings, google-drive-shared-drive, google-drive-file-stream

## *Errors Screenshots*

[**First screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSkLw.png)
[**Second Screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj8T5.png)
[**Third Screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3ccb.png)
[**Fourth Screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhk0q.png)

When the command `ng new <PROJECT_NAME>` is run on the google drive file stream then the above errors are shown, however, no error is shown when the project is created locally and not on the google drive (using file stream on laptop).

Everything is installed correctly i.e. nodejs , npm & angular CLI are installed properly without any fault. (Checked two times before writing this question).

Edit: The solution to the problem is to shift the codebase to local instead of doing it on google drive and if you want to use google drive then don't make the git repository.

Comment: Prakhar, try running the CMD as Administrator because Node needs to read files from the C drive, which contains all system files. You need admin privileges to access it.

Comment: @TheCondorIV , I did as you suggested but it didn't seem to have resolve the problem and still showing the same error , it might be the workflow of google drive file  stream  which is causing the error.